# Store xml elements in tmx file?

Tags: xml, localization, translation

I have source files and translated files in XML format.
I am going to create a tmx (Translation Memory eXchange) file from them using xslt. This is to be able to reuse translations to a greater extent. 
The final output should still be xml files in the same format as the input files.

```
<Area xmlns="xxx" areaNo="1" lang="en">
  <Message number="601">
    <Title>Wrong configuration</Title>
    <Description>Task: <arg format="%s" ordinal="1" /><p />.Not enough info.</Description>
    <Fix>Add some more info.</Fix>
  </Message>
</Area>
```

I am completely new to tmx files and have a design question:
Should I add the XML elements to the tmx file as well, and not just the human language texts?
For instance add:

```
<arg format="%s" ordinal="1" />
<p />
```

to the tmx file and let the translation of those be the same in all languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right approach would be to use TMX placeholder tags () to abstract from the inline XML elements. But it also depends on what tool will be used to translate the XML texts and how the files will be filtered on import. I would recommend to first run a test by importing the XML files into a CAT tool, such as OmegaT, and see how the XML inline elements are stored in the TM.

Comment: OK thanks, I do not yet know which CAT tool to use. I have tried SDL Studio, but unfortunately the automatic alignment is very bad. LF aligner does a very good job with the alignment, but I think it is not meant for XML files. It adds all the XML tags to the tmx. To be able to use OmegaT, I think I have to write my own filter and recompile the entire OmegaT, but maybe that is the way to go.